# Adsense not working on PHP site

Tags: php, html, adsense

I have an active Adsense account that is working on an one site but not the other. The site it is not working on is coded in PHP. I have tried many variations of the code but I am not able to successfully display the ads.
The space for the ad is showing however it is empty. Any ideas?

```
                    <?php
                       $googleadsensecode = "

                       <div class=\"ad\">
                        <script async src=\"//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js\"></script>

                <!-- Responsive Vertical -->
                          <ins class=\"adsbygoogle\"
                               style=\"display:block\"
                               data-ad-client=\"1234567\"
                               data-ad-slot=\"1234567\"
                               data-ad-format=\"auto\"></ins>
                        <script>
                           (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                        </script>

                       </div>";

                    echo $googleadsensecode;
            ?>
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: add \r\n at the end of each line., i had a similar problem.

Comment: @hamboy75 That shouldn't be necessary. HTML doesn't care what kind of whitespace you have between elements.

Comment: I know, html not but javascript yes. He is mixing both, just take care in this case. In some cases, when several javascript lines, you dont need ; at the end if there are \r\n, but when you change it to a php output in a variable, \r\n are not added".

Comment: anyways @Barmar as you see i have added a answer not using \r\n :).

Comment: @hamboy75 His Javascript is just one line, so it doesn't need any special kind of newline in it. It only cares about newlines if it needs to do automatic semicolon insertion between statements on different lines.

Comment: @hamboy75 And Javascript considers both `\r` and `\n` to be a line terminator. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-line-terminators

Comment: @apokryfos no console errors

Answer (score 0):

What I do actually is add this one to the head

```
$head.="<script async src=\"//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js\"></script>";
```

And then create this variable, and just echo where you wants it.

```
$ad600x160px="<ins class=\"adsbygoogle\" style=\"display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px\" data-ad-client=\"ca-pub-xxxxxx\"  data-ad-slot=\"xxxxx\"></ins><script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>";
```

It is what i use actually

In your case

```
$ad="<ins class=\"adsbygoogle\" data-ad-client=\"1234567\" data-ad-slot=\"1234567\" data-ad-format=\"auto\"></ins><script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>";
```

Doing this you load adsbygoogle.js only one time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have implemented the above code in one <php> section within the body (including the $head variable). The ad does not display successfully. Any ideas? (I assume the "." after the $head variable is by mistake correct?)

Comment: Well if you are new in adsense you will need some hours after the creating the account, you dont get ads automatically.

Comment: Anyways take a look to https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/7049023?visit_id=1-636217960640375265-3118511396&rd=1

Comment: no the adsense account is several years old and displaying ads correctly on another website I have running. This website is new on adsense though, do you think that is the issue? Is there anyway to test if the code is otherwise working correctly?

Comment: Take a look to the troubleshooter that i wrote in above line

Comment: yes I have been through the troubleshooter, that is why I came here to validate if there are any errors in the code execution that perhaps I had missed...